# Using Jackson object mapper with Spring Oauth2RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jackson, objectmapper, jackson-databind

I have an api response of the following form:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "field1": "string_1",
            "field2": 2,
            "field3": "string_3",
            "field4": "string_4"
        }
    ]
}
```

which can also be empty:

```
{
    "data": []
}
```

I am calling the API in the following way:

```
apiResponse = oAuth2RestTemplate.exchange(theURL, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, APIResponse.class);
```

I have no control over configuring `oAuth2RestTemplate`, but I can define the `APIResponse` class. How should I define it in a way that the line above does not return the following exception:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: ... cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class DataElements {
    private String field1;
    private int field2;
    private String field3;
    private String field4;

    // constructor and getters and setters
}
```

and

```
@JsonSerialize
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class APIResponse {

    List<DataElements> data;

    // constructor and getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Do your APIResponse and DataElements classes contain default, no-args constructor?

Comment: @Eulodos no, do they have to?

Comment: I believe that Jackson requires no-args constructor to create instances of your classes. Alternatively you could try annotating your constructor with `@JsonCreator` and the also specify `@JsonProperty` on each parameter. Please refer to the [documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html)

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, Jackson does not require you to have default constructor. Please see this example on their [github](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind#annotations-using-custom-constructor)

Comment: @Eulodos actually I put them in and it started working! Do you see anything else wrong?

Comment: I',m not sure if you need this `@JsonSerialize` annotation on your APIResponse class, I believe it's used to provide some additional configuration, see [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Databind-Annotations#serialization-writing-json)

Answer (score 1):

As specified on the Jackson [github](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind#annotations-using-custom-constructor), it does not require your classes to have the default constructor, but it will try to use it if nothing else is available.

Either add the default constructor to your `APIResponse` class or instruct jackson to use an another constructor, specified by you. This can be achieved by annotating the other constructor with `@JsonCreator` and then also its parameters with `@JsonProperty`, see the annotation [docs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html)

So you would end up with something like this:

```
@JsonSerialize
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class APIResponse {

    List<DataElements> data;

    @JsonCreator
    public APIResponse(@JsonProperty("data") List<DataElements> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a good way or not, maybe you can try it

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

ResponseEntity<JSONObject> jsonResponse = oAuth2RestTemplate.exchange(theURL, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, JSONObject.class);
JSONObject response = mapper.convertValue(jsonResponse.getBody(), new TypeReference<JSONObject>(){});
```